# TensorFlow does not Detect GPU on Cluster

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I'm using a cluster to train my Machine Learning Model (TensorFlow) in Jupyter Notebook. The cluster already has JupyterHub (Python 3.7.5), CUDA, and cuDNN installed before I started using it. The cluster is running on Ubuntu 18.04 with GCC Version 8.4.0. When I execute the nvidia-smi command, I get the following output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
(...)
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P4000        On   | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  N/A |
(...)
```

I am not the system administrator, so I installed TensorFlow-GPU using pip. However, when I train the model, Jupyter Notebook and TensorFlow do not detect any GPU, as can be seen below:

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

Output:

```
2.8.3
[]
```

I hope that you can help me.

Here are the steps I have already taken:

- Reinstalled tensorflow packages;
- Installed a different version of Tensorflow;

Comment: Can you verify that you have cuda toolkit available. `nvcc -V` should be an easy way to verify, provided that you have CUDA HOME added to PATH in bashrc.

Comment: Unfortunally I don't have the CUDA toolkit available. When I type `nvcc -V`, the command is not found, so how can I correct this?

On my bashrc I have this:

``export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}$
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin``

Comment: If you have the right paths appended in bashrc and you still don't have `nvcc`, then CUDA toolkit is not installed properly. That could be an issue based on my experience. It might be worthwhile to look at the CUDA docs again: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions.

Comment: My path was incorrect, now that I have corrected it when I run `nvcc -V`:

`Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243`

Comment: Did that help with your TensorFlow issue as well?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I installed the compatible version of TensorFlow with CUDA 10.1, and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. I solved the problem by following the steps below.

1. I used the `ls /usr/local` command to check the installed version of the CUDA Toolkit on the system.
2. I made changes to the PATH file in `.bashrc` as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}$
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

3. I ran source `.bashrc` to apply the changes.
4. Now the `nvcc -V` command is working and showing the correct version for TensorFlow:

```
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

5. `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` and `pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator`
6. `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0` (Compatible with CUDA 10.1 according this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=pt-br#linux))

Now, when I run the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

The output is:

```
2.3.0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux) lists the following specifications:

| Version | Python version | Compiler | Build tools | cuDNN | CUDA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tensorflow-2.9.0 | 3.7-3.10 | GCC 9.3.1 | Bazel 5.0.0 | 8.1 | 11.2 |
| tensorflow-2.8.0 | 3.7-3.10 | GCC 7.3.1 | Bazel 4.2.1 | 8.1 | 11.2 |

With TensorFlow version 2.8.0; GCC 7.3.1 is listed. This could be the reason why TensorFlow does not detect the GPU. I had a similar issue where I used a slightly different version than the one specified and my GPU also did not show up.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried the following this versions of tensorflow 2.11.0, 2.9.0, 2.8.3, 2.8.0 and the same thing happened.